# Simple App Delegate method to show an UIAlertController (in Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uialertview

In obj-C when another iOS app (mail attachment, web link) was tapped with a file or link associated with my app. I would then catch this on openURL or `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and show a `UIAlertView` to confirm the user wants to import the data. Now that `UIAlertView` is depreciated I am trying to do the same thing but not really sure about the best way to do this?

I am having trouble showing a simple alert when my App receives data from another app. This code worked fine in Objective-C with a `UIAlertView`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if (url)
    {
        self.URLString = [url absoluteString];
        NSString *message = @"Received a data exchange request. Would you like to import it?";
        importAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Data Received" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [importAlert show];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

But when I try and switch to `UIAlertViewController` and Swift I can't seem to find a simple way to display the message:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    let URLString: String = url.absoluteString!
    let message: String = "Received data. Would you like to import it?"

    var importAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Data Received", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    importAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    importAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler:
    { action in
        switch action.style {
        case .Default:
            println("default")  
        case .Cancel:
            println("cancel")   
        case .Destructive:
            println("destructive")
        }
    }))

    self.presentViewController(importAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return true
}
```

I get a compile time error that `AppDelegate` does not have a member named `presentViewController`

I have seen some convoluted methods to get the `AppDelegate` to display an `UIAlertViewController` on StackOverflow but I was hoping there was something a little simpler.

All I really need to do is show the user a quick message that they got some data and have them decide what they want to do with it. Once were done my app will continue to open and come to foreground (similar code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` for cold start) with either the new data added or not based on the alert selection.

I could flag a global variable that I check in all my `viewWillAppear` func but this would be a lot of duplication since I have 30+ views.

Let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks

Greg

Comment: presentViewController is a method associated with UIViewController and hence you cannot run this method in the app delegate.

Comment: What you are describing will require notifications. You cannot show any alert to the user outside of the application.

Comment: You will also notice that the app has launched by the time the openUrl delegate method is called.

Comment: In obj-C when another iOS app (mail attachment, web link) was tapped with a file or link associated with my app. I would then catch this on openURL or didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and show a UIAlertView to confirm the user wants to import the data. Now that  UIAlertView is depreciated I am trying to do the same thing but not really sure about the best way to do this?

Any ideas?

Comment: Updated question with intro to clarify it

Comment: Try using self.window.rootViewController.presentViewController(importAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Try using

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(importAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

All you need is a `viewController` object to present the AlertController from.

In Swift 4:

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(importAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What a great answer, wish I had thought of it. ;-)

Comment: Thank you, works exactly like I need it to, only mod is: self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(importAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Nice. If you are doing it in ObjC the code is -- [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];

Comment: How do you then dismiss the alert? I tried this 
var alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { action in
            
                self.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                
            }))
    
            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)

But got the error "Could not find member 'Default'"

Comment: The suggested solution works only when you don't have data restoration enabled. With data restoration active the app will jump right to the place user left it and the message won't appear, the following will be logged: "Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x10519de80> on <YourApp.LoginViewController: 0x102899500> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!". See Marie Amida's answer below on how to handle such a case.

Comment: ... also I found cases when self.window?.rootViewController? might be nil. I've corrected Marie's answer below to have more universal approach.

Answer (score 20):

Use this code to launch alertCV from appdelegate

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
          let importantAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "Hello I was presented from appdelegate ;)", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(importantAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: best answer here, imho. Because of: warning : `Attempt to present <UIAlertController> on <YourViewControllerClass> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`. => Too fast, so `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ...` help us to be in the right time in the right place!

Comment: In my case, I was not receiving any message about window hierarchy... but my viewController insisted in not appear. Thanks, guys.

Comment: This method works. However, just having `self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(importAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method did not work for me probably because the view controller was not created by the time it was called?

Comment: How can i do this in objective c?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've found is the following:

```
        let importantAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "Hello I was presented from appdelegate ;)", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet) //.Alert .ActionSheet
        var hostVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
        while let next = hostVC?.presentedViewController {
            hostVC = next
        }
        hostVC?.presentViewController(importantAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)


        let delay = 1.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            importantAlert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

            return
        }
```

I've added a timer so the UIAlertController is dismissed since it doesn't have any buttons in it.

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33128884/6144027 Brilliant answer on how to present a UIAlertController from AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

From inside the app delegate.

`window.rootViweController.presentViewController..`.

Comment: Haha... we posted the same solution 2 seconds apart!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer in Swift 3 in case it helps anyone:

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(importAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```