# Present UIAlertController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to present a `UIAlertController` from the AppDelegate in my iOS app.
Below is the alert and the present method.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:cTitle message:cMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

//Configure alert and actions

[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

However, when I try to present the alert, it doesn't appear and I get the following alert in the console.

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x145f5d60> on <UINavigationController: 0x146590f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

What is causing the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Trying to present right as the app is launching I'm guessing?

Comment: Can you try this link for usefull Link: [ alertViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37029075/2442762)

Answer (score 32):

You can use this code as well if you want to launch it from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.Hope this helps.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
              let importantAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "Hello I was presented from appdelegate ;)", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(importantAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
```

And up-to-date:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello!", message: "Greetings from AppDelegate.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi @AdiQuadCore, your is useful only in swift application. In objC, the `UIAlertController` needs a pointer to the current `UIViewController`.

Comment: This worked for me in ObjC in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 20):

try this code..

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application               didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
 NSLog(@"rakshapettu");
 UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"AlertView" message:@"I am an AlertView" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                          [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                      }];
[alert addAction:defaultAction];
UIWindow *alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
alertWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
[alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
[alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: How is the `UIWindow` deallocated?

Answer (score 13):

It's better to use something like:

```
var hostVC = self.window?.rootViewController

while let next = hostVC?.presentedViewController {
    hostVC = next
}

hostVC?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Previous answers won't work if you are already presenting modal view controller.

Comment: Perfect answer and a really good method to handle modally presented view controllers! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

you call it before the window is up and the navigationController is actually shown:

"Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

likely you do so in applicationDidFinishLaunching?

---

EITHER wait .. like do it when the view really appears

OR

one 'hack' would be to force the view and window up yourself:

```
[self.window addSubview:self.rootViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: If you aren't not *creating* a new Window, do you still have to do `makeKeyAndVisible`? For window that comes with AppDelegate, doesn't that happen by default?!

Comment: In General: yes BUT It happens too late for the op's question

Comment: I'm confused. what do you mean too late? Is your code correct or not?

Comment: Mine is correct for the given question :) makeKeyAndVisible is needed here

Answer (score 3):

I was trying the same but does not work because after change of viewcontroller still returned the initial viewcontroller and throw the error `whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`. Finally, I found the solution to this problem:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I have to force view controllers to update de `keyWindow` with this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController = self
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: You should not do that, really.

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling it in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. I had a similar error and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Alert Controller:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

    //INTERNET NOT AVAILABLE ALERT
    var internetUnavailableAlertController = UIAlertController (title: "Network Unavailable", message: "Please check your internet connection settings and turn on Network Connection", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    var settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .Default) { (_) -> Void in
        let settingsUrl = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
        if let url = settingsUrl {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }
    var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    internetUnavailableAlertController .addAction(settingsAction)
    internetUnavailableAlertController .addAction(cancelAction)
    self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(internetUnavailableAlertController , animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

Using AlertView:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        //INTERNET NOT AVAILABLE ALERTVIEW

        let internetUnavailableAlert =  UIAlertView(title: "Network Unavailable", message: "Please check your internet connection settings and turn on Network Connection", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
        internetUnavailableAlert.show()
        })

  return true
 }
}
```

Comment: UIAlertView is now deprecated.