# Issue while showing alert on window?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am setting root view controller of my app from below code

```
let navController = UINavigationController()
    //App Theming
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = Constant.AppColor.navigationColor
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = Constant.AppColor.navigationBarTintColor
    navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: Constant.AppColor.navigationColorTextColor]
    navController.pushViewController(viewContoller, animated: true)
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navController
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Now after I set one controller as root. Then I show alert on the window from below code.

```
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
     window.addSubView(mainView)
```

But the alert does not show up. please let me know what is the issue ? I am not able to understand .

**EDIT:**
On app launch I call the api in app background thread so I get session expire & on session expire I am showing alert to user. So by the time alert is shown & new controller if navigated which hides the alert because new controller is crated .After that I try to show alert then it does not work

Comment: see this once may be it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155769/how-to-show-uialertcontroller-from-appdelegate/36156077

Comment: can u please post code of alert?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show UIAlertController from Appdelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155769/how-to-show-uialertcontroller-from-appdelegate)

Comment: Check my answer: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49506453/4061501)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Present UIAlertController from AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952061/present-uialertcontroller-from-appdelegate)

Comment: @Techiee where did you put the above code? Is your alert a `UIAlertController` ? Where do you want to show it?

Comment: I am not using any UIAlertViewController. I am adding a custom view window & showing , hiding It with animation.

Comment: @Techiee Please make your question clearer and someone will give you a right answer. I don't know why you need `appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navController` when showing alert and what is `mainView`? One more, where did you put the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `window.addSubView(mainView)` to show the alert.

Use a viewController that manages `mainView` and present it from the rootViewController.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html on how to present a viewController

Comment: I have made a custom class  for this so I can't get the current controller object

Comment: You want to present an alert from a custom class? This has been discussed a few times. (e.g.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155769/how-to-show-uialertcontroller-from-appdelegate)

Comment: Why do I need to create a new UIWindow() object every time I show an alert. I can use appdelegate window for that

Comment: Normally an alert is displayed by a view controller and you can use the present method there. But if you are in a class that is not a ViewController or has no reference to a ViewController, things are more complicated.

Comment: I can't change the approach of showing the alert on view controller because I have reached so far in my code

Comment: Than check then following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller

Answer (score 0):

First add root `viewcontroller` like this then add code for alert on `viewdidappear` in your view controller

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let object  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"yourViewController") as! yourViewController            
let addNavi = UINavigationController(rootViewController: object)
```

`self.window?.rootViewController = addNavi
 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`

Comment: ` DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // add alert code
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You can not show any alert on `UIwindow`, `UINavigationController` and on `UItabbarController` because these all are indicate to root.

You need to show on any `UIViewcontroller` object.